# Extract all the data from current date to 2 years back in SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

The below table having 1000 rows but here let's consider 3 rows:

| Date | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-24 | Selena | 1234 |
| 2021-02-01 | Katy | 6789 |
| 2020-04-30 | Snoop | 4324 |

I want to extract all the data from last two years to current date.
For instance,
Today's date is : 28-07-2022

I want the data from 28-07-2020 to 28-07-2022

My code should always take today's date to last 2 year every time it runs.

Comment: Everything you need is in the documentation : [BigQuery Date Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)

Comment: A couple of things to ask - what is the actual data type of the column labeled "Date" - is it showing a format other than SQL date type. Second question is - which database are you using - it could vary according to mysql/ms-sqlserver/db2/db2x/... etc.   - I think you'll find your answers ultimately according to MatBailie's reference link.   Cheers!

Comment: Date columns is of date type. I'm using GCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an example query (mysql)

```
select *
from mytable 
where mycol_dt >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTH)
```

Looks like GCP uses "CURRENT_DATE()" though instead of "CURDATE()" . A minor tweak. I'll leave it as-is to be mindful of those that may be using other databases.

In this example the DATE_SUB clause takes in a data and INTERVAL parameters, and returns the date that represents the difference. Depending on what granularity you need you may need to use a DAY interval or perhaps YEAR.  
(Leap year logic may also affect what you get back, and may mean you'll need to delve into using TSQL or some high-level language logic to customize the query. That depends on your requirements.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
where mycol_dt >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTH)?

Since I want last 2 years of data from current date?

Also, by using this, I'm getting another column with Boolean values and not showing the date.

Comment: ? Is it still giving the unexpected result?  If so could you post the result (or a small sample?

Comment: No, yeah it worked.. It is giving thr output as boolean but i put the condition in where clause that the date = "true"! It's working now! Thanks a ton for the help. :)